# cal-heatmap works locally, however errors after heroku deployment

Tags: angular, heroku, typescript, angular-cli, cal-heatmap

I have an instance of cal-heatmap running fine on my Angular 2 (angular-cli) project locally. When I deploy the project to heroku it builds successfully, however I get the following errors in the console and my cal-heatmap doesn't show:

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix this as I don't think I should be editing the cal-heatmap.js file. The line in the file the first error is referring to is as follows:

```js
getDayOfYear: d3.time.format("%j"),
```

I've made sure that I have referenced both d3.js and cal-heatmap.js correctly in my project.

Is this a typings thing? I thought it was, so I included the following in my package.json dependencies however it made no difference:

- "@types/d3": "~4.4.1"
- "@types/cal-heatmap": "~3.5.31"

Any idea how I can correct this and get cal-heatmap running on my heroku instance?

**UPDATE**
I was referencing the very latest version of d3.js, so I decided to try referencing the recommended version on http://cal-heatmap.com/ (v3.5.6). I now get the following errors:

[image]

I'm still unsure what needs to be done to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. The later error was because the #cal-heatmap div could not be found. I this it was because I placed a *ngIf condition on the #cal-heatmap div (for the purposes of displaying a spinner whilst the cal-heatmap loaded). This caused a problem whereby the code couldn't find the #cal-heatmap div because it didn't exist / wasn't shown yet. All I needed to do was remove the *ngIf condition and the cal-heatmap loaded / displayed.

I believe the initial problem did relate to a more recent version of d3.js being referenced, so I made sure I referenced v3.5.6 too.